# Reshaping, overlapping columns of array into vector in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, reshape, overlap

I want to reshape an array into a vector by its columns, and I want to have an offset between each column, with the overlapping elements added together. 
Any ideas? I've done it using a double for-loop but I was hoping for something more efficient...

```
for i=1:b                   
    for j=1:a
        overlap=j+(i-1)*offset;
        vector(overlap) = vector(overlap) + (array(j,i));
end
end
```

for example I want to have:

```
[ 1 4 7 ] 
[ 2 5 8 ]
[ 3 6 9 ]
```

and an offset of 1 between columns, then I want to get as a vector the following:

```
[ 1 2 7 5 13 8 9 ]
```

**edit** I thought of appending zeros and then adding per column like this

```
[ 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 ]
[ 0 0 4 5 6 0 0 ]
[ 0 0 0 0 7 8 9 ]
```

and then use sum per column in order to get a new vector with elements the sum of the columns. 
Does anyone know of a quick way to create such diagonal matrices?

Comment: "I want to have an offset between each column, with the overlapping elements added together." please explain using an example

Comment: i.e. the last x elements of the first column should be added to the first x elements of the next column.

Comment: how about a numerical example of a small matrix converted in your desired format?

Comment: sure I'll edit my post above. **-edited**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you need is a general formula for this matrix:

```
[ 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 ]
[ 0 0 4 5 6 0 0 ]
[ 0 0 0 0 7 8 9 ]
```

This is a little easier if we rewrite the matrix as follows:

```
[ 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 5 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 8 9 ]
```

I'll state without proof that the number of zeros between each set of non-zero numbers is equal to:

```
nz = (size(array,1) - overlap) * size(array,2);
```

You should be able to convince yourself that this is true fairly easily. Now we can do the following:

```
vector = [array;zeros(nz,size(array,2)];
vector = vector(1:end-nz);
```

which gives

```
vector = [ 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 5 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 8 9 ]
```

then we just reshape and sum:

```
vector = sum(reshape(vector,[],size(array,2))');
vector =
     1     2     7     5    13     8     9
```

Comment: thanks! but why not reshape at the start like 
    
    vector=reshape(array',1,21); ?

Comment: Using your code on array=[ 1 2 3 0 0 0 0; 0 0 4 5 6 0 0; 0 0 0 0 7 8 9];

I get the following vector [1 0 2 0 3 4 0 5 0 6 7 0 8 0 9 ]

Comment: I thought `array = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]`?

Comment: true, but with that one I get `vector=[1 4 9 5 11 6 9]`

Comment: Ah, sorry. The array you showed in your original question was `[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]'`. Note the transpose. That was what I was working from.

Comment: actually `array = [1 4 7 ; 2 5 8 ; 3 6 9 ]` gives `vector = 1 6 15 14 9`

Comment: Are you sure? I just tried it using what I have in my answer exactly, and I got `[1     2     7     5    13     8     9]`. I guess I should check, are you using an overlap of 1?

Comment: you're right! I had changed the overlap to 2, my bad. It works! Thanks again!

Comment: what strikes me though is that this solution is slower than the double for loop…it might be my slow memory...care to try both and compare?